# Laravel 5.4 with Pusher Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastException' with message '404 NOT FOUND

Tags: php, laravel-5, broadcast, pusher

I'm attempting to get Pusher working with Laravel 5.4, but I keep running into the push failing in the queue.
I've tested the Channel from the Pusher debug console and it works without issue.
I can also see the browser listening on the chosen channel.
I've followed the setup on the Pusher getting started page. 
I've used artisan to clear config and cache, done a httpd restart as well to be sure.

I don't know if I am missing a step, or something else. I've seen this question asked a few times on here, but each solution which I've encorporated below, doesn't resolve the issue.

Hoping someone can come up with a suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

**Setup**

*.env* (Setup, and checked is working correctly):

```
APP_URL=*****
DB_HOST=*****
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
PUSHER_APP_ID=******
PUSHER_APP_KEY=*******************
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=***********************
```

*broadcasting.php* (Added CURL options, no success):

```
    'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => config('services.pusher.app_key'),
        'secret' => config('services.pusher.app_secret'),
        'app_id' => config('services.pusher.app_id'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => 'ap4',
            'useTLS' => true,
            'curl_options' => [
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
            ]
        ],
    ],
```

*TicketComment.php (Event)*

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class TicketComment implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $tries = 5;

    public $username;

    public $message;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->message  = "{$username} liked your status";
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return ['status-liked'];
    }

    public function broadcastAs() {

        return 'event-liked';

    }
}
```

*global.js (front-end js)*:

```
    var _notificationListener = function(){
        // Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
        Pusher.logToConsole = true;

        var pusher = new Pusher('*******************', {
            cluster: 'ap4',
            encrypted: true
        });

        var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
        channel.bind('event-liked', function(data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
}
```

*Queue (Exception)*:

```
exception 'Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastException' with message '404 NOT FOUND
' in /var/www/html/php56/ml/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/Broadcasters/PusherBroadcaster.php:106
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/php56/ml/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/BroadcastEvent.php(49): Illuminate\Broadcasting\Broadcasters\PusherBroadcaster->broadcast(Array, 'event-liked', Array)
#1 [internal function]: Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent->handle(Object(Illuminate\Broadcasting\Broadcasters\PusherBroadcaster))
#2 /var/www/html/php56/ml/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(30): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 /var/www/html/php56/ml/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#4 /var/www/html/php56/ml/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#5 /var/www/html/php56/ml/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(539): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#6 /var/www/html/php56/ml/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(94): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#7 /var/www/html/php56/ml/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(114): Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher->Illuminate\Bus\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent))
#8 /var/www/html/php56/ml/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent))
#9 /var/www/html/php56/ml/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(98): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#10 /var/www/html/php56/ml/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php(43): Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher->dispatchNow(Object(Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent), NULL)
#11 /var/www/html/php56/ml/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php(69): Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler->call(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), Array)
#12 /var/www/html/php56/ml/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(317): Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job->fire()
#13 /var/www/html/php56/ml/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(267): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->process('database', Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#14 /var/www/html/php56/ml/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(224): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->runJob(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), 'database', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#15 /var/www/html/php56/ml/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(102): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->runNextJob('database', 'default', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#16 /var/www/html/php56/ml/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(86): Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->runWorker('database', 'default')
#17 [internal function]: Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->fire()
#18 /var/www/html/php56/ml/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(30): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#19 /var/www/html/php56/ml/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#20 /var/www/html/php56/ml/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#21 /var/www/html/php56/ml/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(539): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#22 /var/www/html/php56/ml/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(182): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#23 /var/www/html/php56/ml/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#24 /var/www/html/php56/ml/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(168): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#25 /var/www/html/php56/ml/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(963): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#26 /var/www/html/php56/ml/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(254): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#27 /var/www/html/php56/ml/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(147): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#28 /var/www/html/php56/ml/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(122): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#29 /var/www/html/php56/ml/artisan(36): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#30 {main}
```

Comment: Try removing the APP_URL from your .env file.

Comment: @doydoy attempted that before, did nothing. I can do a push from the Pusher debug console, and that works.

Answer (score 0):

You may try `php artisan config:cache` command. Did the trick for me to working.

```
var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
```

Here you are subscribing to my channel but from the event.

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return ['status-liked'];// ->channel 'status-liked' should be replace by 'my-channel'
}
```

Comment: I had tried that, and composer dump autoload, neither made a difference. I've since gone to PHP7.2 and Laravel 7 and gotten this working